# Not able to publish on rpub

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have recently started using Rmarkdown.
I thought to publish all my work on Rpub using the publish tab on Rstudio.
I am constantly getting following error
**SSL certificate problem ,verify that the CA cert is ok**
Please post a solution.
P.S i cant post a image since i don't have yet required points.

Comment: probably worth asking this on the RStudio user forum instead.